# Pass input value to a empty div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input box that when the user type a sentence it will pass it to a empty box(div).I have some of the code where I grab the value, but I can't figured out how to pass that data one by one to the empty box every time they click submit.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control border" id="skills-box">

$( ".btn-add" ).click(function() {
value = $("#skills-box").val(); 
$(value).append( $(".label-primary"));
});
```

Comment: $('value').append( $(".label-primary")); wrong

Comment: $('.label-primary').append( value ); right

Comment: First. Anything within quotes is a string character. Use variable names as they are. Second. Learn how does `jQuery` function works. And `.append`.

Comment: I do not believe that `append` is needed at all.

Comment: the quotes was my mistake sorry about that. thank you for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the value to the element class, in this case taht would be the .label-primary div tag. It would go something like this.

```
$(".btn-add").click(function() {

    var value = $("#skills-box").val(); 
    $('.label-primary').append(value);

});
```

I got it working in jsbin, here is the link:
[EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/sarohabojuci/4/edit)

Answer (score 1):

use this script

```
$('.skills-box').on('blur',function(e){
  $('.display-box').append(this.value);
});
```

Complete Code:
    
    
    
    
    Jquery

```
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Here..." class="skills-box">
<div class="display-box"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.skills-box').on('blur',function(e){
  $('.display-box').append(this.value);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(value).append( $(".label-primary"));` to:

```
$(value).appendTo( ".label-primary" );
```